# Android:onclick behavior

Tags: android, onclick, android-view

The syntax for triggering a function whenever a button is hit is usually

```
android:onclick="somefunction".
```

What I notice is that the function triggered always has a parameter `(View view)`, yet in the syntax above I don't see any thing passed into it.
Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: The snippet you show is from the XML and is not Java. Somewhere in the Android pipeline (not sure where) it looks up the name of the function in the Java code and calls it with the view.

Comment: Read the documentation it will clearly explain you the working of onClickListener .
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Comment: Thanks! So what specific view is passed into the onclick function? I'm still not sure what does the view refer to in this case

Comment: @rustyengineer The view that was clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters view in this case is the button that is clicked

From:

> [Android UI Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

Within the various View classes that you'll use to compose your layout, you may notice several public callback methods that look useful for UI events. These methods are called by the Android framework when the respective action occurs on that object. For instance, when a View (such as a Button) is touched, the onTouchEvent() method is called on that object. However, in order to intercept this, you must extend the class and override the method. However, extending every View object in order to handle such an event would not be practical. This is why the View class also contains a collection of nested interfaces with callbacks that you can much more easily define. These interfaces, called event listeners, are your ticket to capturing the user interaction with your UI.

Comment: @rustyengineer if this answered your question, don't forget check as correct ;-)